# Should I use const_cast?

Tags: c++

So I'm doing some parsing of C-strings in a function that looks like this:

```
void parse(const char** params, int numParams);
```

I wanted to pull some information out of one of the strings stored in params, so I wrote code that looked like this:

```
char* charPointer;
charPointer = params[0];
```

The compiler didn't like this and told me that it can't convert from a const char* to a char*. I understand the reasoning behind this (in theory I could write to the address pointed to by charPointer but not by params[0] if it let me) but what I don't understand is how I should be getting around it. I know of two ways to fix this error but I don't know which one is "proper" or really what the differences are between them. The first is:

```
const char* charPointer;
charPointer = params[0];
```

And the second method is:

```
char* charPointer;
charPointer = const_cast<char*>(params[0]);
```

So which is better and why?

Comment: It's `const`. Declare your pointer accordingly. Don't un-`const` it because it's supposed to be read-only, do not touch. This is like un-screwing all the bolts on your chair and hoping it won't fall apart.

Comment: Quite often when you are resulting to using casts you are doing something wrong

Comment: Ok, but why? If I const_cast it does that mean I can write to that memory address even though in theory I shouldn't be able to?

Comment: Why split the declarations and initializations onto different lines?  `const char* charPointer = params[0]` is clear enough to me.  C++ doesn't require you to declare everything at the beginning of a block like C used to (C hasn't required it since 1999).

Comment: "can write to that memory address even though in theory I shouldn't be able to?" -> the compiler won't stop you from trying (if you don't cast, you get a compiler error letting you know something's wrong), but then you will often get inconsistent results and you can undefined behavior ( http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html ).

Comment: In the actual code charPointer is set to NULL immediately and this is only assigned later. I concatenated them for the purposes of my question :)

Comment: One big issue when you remove const from `const char*` in particular is that a lot of the time `const char*` could point to a string literal (such as `const char* foo = "bar"`). This is something that is stored in a special part of the address space and having a non-const pointer to that is no bueno.

Comment: Thou shall not cast.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`const_cast` is safe only, if pointer is *really* pointing to something which is non-const, so modifying it is not a problem. If the value is originally `const`, then using `const_cast` to get rid of the constness and then writing to it is basically undefined behaviour (for example, other parts of the code may assume value does not change, so your modification only takes effect sometimes).

So definitely use this version:

```
const char* charPointerr = params[0];
```

In general, if you need to resort to `const_cast`, you are probably doing something... if not wrong, then at least ugly. And if you are not sure if it is just ugly or outright wrong, then it's probably wrong.

---

Example of something where things can go horribly wrong due to undefined behaviour like this:

```
const bool do_it = true;
bool *ptr = const_cast<bool*>(&do_it);
*ptr = false;

// optimizer probably thinks this is always true
if (do_it) initiate_nuclear_first_strike();
```

While developing using debug build, everything seems to work. Then, release build is deployed (without testing, of course, because in hurry), and *BOOM*, end of the world. UB is dangerous like that (a side note: effects of UB can also be totally obscure and not as easily understandable as this example).

Comment: Even better. const objects might be put into read-only regions of the memory, so modifying those will give you a hardware exception.

Comment: I agree with your point: that casting away const is dangerous and usually wrong-headed. The analysis isn't quite right, though. The cast is legal regardless of what the pointer being converted points to; **writing** through the resulting pointer is only valid if the underlying object is modifiable. In the code snippet, the line that assigns to `ptr` is fine; it's the next line that isn't.

Comment: Got it. So basically the compiler might optimize assuming that the value at the address pointed to by params[0] isn't changing, which screws things up when I go and change that data.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks, clarified!

Answer (score 4):

> So which is better and why?

```
const char* charPointer;
charPointer = params[0];
```

is certainly better, than forcibly removing a restriction using the

```
char* charPointer;
charPointer = const_cast<char*>(params[0]);
```

Parsing the character array usually shouldn't need to change it, thus its best to leave it `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Casting is almost always a code smell. The only legitimate use I've ever found for `const_cast` is to pass const data to a legacy library function which you know won't modify the data, but was written in the ancient days without the const specifier.

Why would you want to cast it away, anyway? In this instance, you don't need to. Const correctness is a great boon to writing correct code. I've found that making everything const that doesn't need to change is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

**const_cast** is safe only if you're casting a variable that was originally non-const. For example, if you have a function that takes a parameter of a const char *, and you pass in a **modifiable char ***, it's safe to const_cast that parameter back to a char * and modify it. However, if the original variable was in fact const, then using const_cast will result in **undefined behavior**

```
const char* charPointer = params[0];
```

is the better way to do that and also better to initialize and declare in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a pointer to const to a pointer to non-const allows you to write to constant objects through the pointer.

Writing to constant objects is *undefined behaviour*.

The C++ language specification is very explicit about what happens when you invoke undefined behaviour - **the entire logic of the program** becomes undefined, the compiler is under **no obligation to behave reasonably**, and it becomes **impossible to reason about how the program will behave** - at all - even in unrelated parts of the program.

Knowing this, ask yourself the question again. :-)